# I liked the plant I spotted in the city - but what is it?

Tags: identification

I walked down a street tonight, and spotted an unusual plant that I liked very much. Can you perhaps ID it?

How come this plant flowers in November?

Pictures were taken today, continental european climate zone 8a.

First four pics are all of one specimen, and the fifth one pictures another specimen, but apparently of the same species.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: VIvidD, can you give us an idea of what temperature it is where you live? It would help us in general, but especially because you're wondering if should be flowering in November. Thanks!

Comment: Also, what city are these plants located? By any chance can you get any pictures of them during the day? With identification questions, we appreciate more information. The [identification tag description](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/tags/identification/info) has a good explanation of how best to write an identification question. Thanks!

Comment: @Sue, I updated the question with hardiness zone. It is not easy for me to take photos during the day time, but I will try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 'continental european climate' doesn't  mean very much - European countries range in temperature at this time of year from -10 deg C to around 22 deg C, but, assuming you're not somewhere it's below zero, I suspect it's Mirabilis jalapa - it's hard to be certain because the pictures have been taken after dark, but this plant is hardy down to -5 deg C; a frost will decimate the flowers though. Judging by the size of the plants, they will have been in flower for some months, and will just keep going until the weather gets too cold or a frost knocks them back. Info here https://www.rhs.org.uk/Plants/11156/i-Mirabilis-jalapa-i/Details

Comment: Thanks! Continental climate european area temperature range at any time of year is much smaller than you mention. But the range for a particular day or time of year is not even important, the overall yearly weather cycle is, and it is very consistent for the whole area of continental climate.

Comment: -2 forecast in Moscow tonight - I'm in the UK, have relatives in various parts of Europe - so depends whether you mean EU countries or simply the European continent when you refer to 'continental climate'. You didn't say EU, just Europe, hence my suggested possible temperature ranges in November.... In winter, Vilnius  and Riga can have -35deg C when Brittany is around 6 deg C, so there is a large variation